# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php, wget

I have this php code that I will use to run wget on linux

```
<?php

include 'theme.php';
ceklogin();
css();

if($_POST['wget-send'])
{
  $dir=$_POST['dir'];
  $link=$_POST['link'];
  exec('cd '.$dir,$out);
  exec('echo '.$link' > /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
  exec('wget -i /tmp/wget-download-link.txt -o /tmp/wget.log -c -t 100 -w 10',$out);
  echo $out[2];
  exit();
}

echo "<br><br><form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
echo "Download directory :<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"dir\" size=\"15\" value=\"/mnt/usb/\"/><br>";
echo '<br>Download link :<br>';
echo "<textarea name=\"link\" rows=\"4\" cols=\"35\"></textarea><br><br>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="wget-send" value="Send" />';
echo "</form></div>";

foot();
echo '
</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';

?>
```

When I try to run the php it gives me this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' > /tmp/wget-download-link.tx' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /www/wget.php on line 10
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: `'.$link'` -> `'.$link.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a `.` after `$link` in this line:

```
exec('echo '.$link.' > /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a `.` on this line:

```
exec('echo '.$link.' > /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
```

Answer (score 0):

This site isn't for your basic syntax debugging errors, but here you go anyway.

```
exec('echo '.$link' > /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
```

You're missing the `.` after `$link`

Should be

```
exec('echo '.$link.' > /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
```